# Unable to go to design view in VS 2008 after installing RIA

Tags: visual-studio-2008

On my aspx pages I see just a white screen, no controls, after installing RIA and Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble installing Silverlight too. What I had to do was:

```
1) Install VS from scratch. 
2) Install VS service packs. 
3) Install silverlight. 
4) Install VS tools for silverlight.
```

Then it worked for me.